# How we will relate question asked here with other technologies?

Tags: discussion

How can we will relate question asked here with other technologies like .net, jquery, mvc etc so that other experts can answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

Same way as it is done on Stack Overflow I would suggest, so just tag questions with the appropriate technology as well. However we should be careful not to "overtag" something (if that's a word ;o) and try to attract too many non Tridion experts.

For example this question [Unable to load .Net dll while publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906949/tridion-unable-to-load-net-dll-while-publishing), it was answered quite fast by somebody with .net knowledge (since tagged accordingly). But because he did not understand the context of the question (it's SDL Tridion related), his answer did not make sense and got down-voted. He eventually deleted his own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the downsides of having our own site. .NET experts, XSLT experts, etc. who are not part of our community will not see questions that perhaps they could have helped with.

Get over it! :-)

Obviously, if a question is genuinely more about C# than modular templating, or whatever, then people shouldn't post it here, but instead on SO or wherever. If they get that wrong, we should help by commenting, downvoting, closing, etc.

On the plus side, for most questions that are truly Tridion-related, even those which cross over into other technologies, our own community probably has experts that can answer them well, while also considering the Tridion context.

So - it's a non-problem.